# Chrome Dev Tools - Chrome - Clear History, Cache and Cookies?

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to find a way to clear history, cache and cookies in android chrome with chrome dev tools. I didn't find anything in the protocol.json file of chrome dev tools.

There is a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In protocol.json Network has a clearBrowserCookies command and Page has deleteCookie command.

Comment: But how can I delete the history? It only for debugging. The ADB is also enabled.